# How to hide two buttons in GvrView

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtual-reality

In google's Cardboard API we can use `CardboardView.setSettingsButtonEnabled(boolean)` method to hide the settings button on the bottom of the screen.
[image]
    Now,Google VR API is graded to 1.0. Use `GvrView` insteads of 'CardboardView', and the settings button is moved to top|right when adding a close button on left|top, but I can't find any GvrView's methods which can hide the two buttons.
    Please help me how to fix it, Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, see here - https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/69

Comment: I think you are right. The developers dosen't plan to add this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version (1.170.0) of the GVR SDK. You can find the buttons and remove them (but only in older versions of Android):

```
// Settings Button
val settingsButton = gvrView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ui_settings_button)
settingsButton.visibility = View.GONE

// Back Button
val backButton = gvrView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ui_back_button)
backButton.visibility = View.GONE

// Alignment Marker
val alignmentMarker = gvrView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.ui_alignment_marker)
alignmentMarker.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: It's easier this way:  gvrView.findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,I think the developers don't plan to add this method.
[https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/252][1]